# Using CRUD in an asp.net MVC application without Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to achieve CRUD operation in MVC using SQL without using the Entity Framework. I've done well with insert but when coming to Update, View details and delete I am confused how to perform, so can some one help me out?

This is my code for creating:

My Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


namespace Test.Models
{
    public class Customers
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Address Line 1")]
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Address Line 2")]
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "City")]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Postcode")]
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Phone No")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString.ToString();


        public void insert(Customers customers)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
            {
                string sql = "insert into Customers values('" + customers.FirstName + "','" + customers.LastName + "','" + customers.AddressLine1 + "','" + customers.AddressLine2 + "','" + customers.City + "','" + customers.Postcode + "','" + customers.Phone + "')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Test.Models;

namespace Test.Controllers
{
    public class CustomersController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Customers
        public ActionResult AddCustomerForm()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddCustomerForm(FormCollection formCollection)
        {

            Customers customers = new Customers();
            customers.FirstName = formCollection["FirstName"];
            customers.LastName = formCollection["LastName"];
            customers.AddressLine1 = formCollection["AddressLine1"];
            customers.AddressLine2 = formCollection["AddressLine2"];
            customers.City = formCollection["City"];
            customers.Postcode = formCollection["Postcode"];
            customers.Phone = formCollection["Phone"];

            customers.insert(customers);
            return View("CustomerRegSuccess", customers);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: EntityFramework provides very fast and easy way to deal with database operation, then why do you want to perform database operation using ADO.Net? Is there any specific reason to do so?

Comment: Would it still be possible to use advanced sql statements for reporting purposes etc?

Comment: Yes, entity framework allows to work with both entities and Stored procedures as well. So we can execute advanced SQL logic against SQL SERVER using entity framework.

Comment: Ok, how is that done?

Comment: You can refer several tutorials on entity framework available on the internet to get in depth. Here is an example how you can execute stored procs using entity framework.   SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[1];
            parameters[0] = new SqlParameter("@param1", value);
            ((DbContext)this.context).Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec uspDemoProc @param", parameters);

Comment: @AshishShukla Yes, Entity Framework is amazing but not all places of employment have adopted it (or for that matter ever will), answers to questions like this could help those of us that are forced into using older technologies.

Comment: Still entity framework is a slower one. Try to use dapper ORM. https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/dapper-vs-entity-framework-vs-ado-net-performance-benchmarking/